# Gradle String Boot multi-projects, expand application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-properties

I'm using gradle to manage a multi-modules spring boot project.

> ->Root
>
> ---> module-1
> --------->src/main/java
> --------->src/test/java/application.properties
>
> ---> module-2
> --------->src/main/java
> --------->src/test/java/application.properties
>
> ---> SHARED-FOLDER
> ---------> data.json

In my test `application.properties` of `module-1` I want to reference `SHARED-FOLDER/data.json` file, something like :

**application.properties**

`my.json.data.file=SHARED-FOLDER/data.json`

But it's not working. I've tried :

`my.json.data.file=${user.dir}/SHARED-FOLDER/data.json`

but `user.dir` references `module-1`not `root`

How can I reference `root/SHARED-FOLDER/data.json` in an application.properties inside another module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to add the shared folder to my classpath and then reference it like :

`my.json.data.file=classpath:data.json`

In my gradle sub-modules I've added :

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            resources {
                srcDirs += [
                        "$rootDir/SHARED-FOLDER"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```